# react-native android: security settings are blocking Metro server

Tags: android, react-native, admob

I am trying to set up Admob mediation with Facebook Audience Network. The tutorial here
https://developers.facebook.com/docs/audience-network/android-network-security-config

suggest that I modify my Android security config with this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<network-security-config>
...
<domain-config cleartextTrafficPermitted="true">
<domain includeSubdomains="true">127.0.0.1</domain>
</domain-config>
...
</network-security-config>
```

However when I do this, my app stops working in dev mode:

[image]

The Metro server is running. I am perfectly able to access `http://127.0.0.1:8081` from my mobile Chrome. It's just that this security setting blocks my app from fetching the JS bundle from this address.

Currently I am disabling this security config while developing the app and enabling it again when building the production bundle, but this is not sustainable long-term.

How do I work around that?

Comment: Did you try to add the localhost to your security config and load the metro?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

adding this

```
<domain includeSubdomains="true">localhost</domain>
```

helped

Answer (score 0):

Same problem, in my case, I have to add this line too:

```
<domain includeSubdomains="true">10.0.2.2</domain>
```

I think because is the port where metro is running.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).